# Typeset enumerated math formulas with nested braces

Tags: math-mode

How to typeset the following math formula?

[image]

I just can't do that beautifully

Comment: Welcome to the site TeX.SE. The tag `latex3` is not very correct.

Comment: Note this is  Q&A site, not a _please do this for me_ service. What do you have so far.

Comment: Search for `\rcases` and `\left\}` in latex

Comment: Can you please choose a title that describes your problem? In its current form it won't help any future users of this site who might have the same problem as you.

Answer (score 8):

You should try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left.\begin{aligned}
1)&\left.
\begin{aligned}
\sum\vv*{F}{x}&=0\\
\sum\vv*{F}{y}&=0
\end{aligned}
\right\rbrace\\
2)&\sum\vv{M}=0
\end{aligned}
\right\rbrace 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]